# Why does the print function return None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Why does the outer `print` in this code display `None`?

```
>>> a = print(print("Python"))
Python
None
>>> print(type(a))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Why does `a` become `None` here, even though `hey` is printed (rather than `None`)?

```
>>> a = print("hey")
hey
>>> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

---

<sub>See also: [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `print()` function returns `None`. You are printing that return value.

That's because `print()` has nothing *to* return; its job is to write the arguments, after converting them to strings, to a file object (which defaults to `sys.stdout`). But all expressions in Python (including calls) produce a value, so in  such cases `None` is produced.

You appear to confuse printing with returning here. The Python interactive interpreter *also* prints; it prints the result of expressions run directly in on the prompt, provided they don't produce `None`:

```
>>> None
>>> 'some value'
'some value'
```

The string was echoed (printed) to your terminal, while `None` was not.

Since `print()` returns `None` but writes to the same output (your terminal), the results may *look* the same, but they are very different actions. I can make `print()` write to something else, and you won't see anything on the terminal:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> output = StringIO()
>>> print('Hello world!', file=output)
>>> output.getvalue()
'Hello world!\n'
```

The `print()` function call did not produce output on the terminal, and returned `None` which then was not echoed.

Comment: @sacma: **printing** is not the same thing as **returning**.

Comment: So `print` always returning `None` ?

Comment: Yes. Check the documentation.

Comment: @Matthias: the `print()` function documentation does not explicitly mention `None` is returned (because that's the default).

Comment: That's what I wanted to say. (Yes, I checked the documentation before commenting.)