# Find if an input is in a list

Tags: python, list

Trying to get an input from the user (which the computer accepts) and then checks if it is in a list. Afterwards, it starts to play the game. Any advice?

```
if answer == "2":
    f = open("users.txt", "r")    
    x = str(input("Please enter a valid username: "))
    for line in f:
         usernab = print(line.strip())
         if (x) in (usernab):
                for x in range(0,5):
                       #Do something.
```

Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/NEA/Project/backup.py", line 20, in <module>
if (x) in (usernab):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: do you have empty lines in your `users.txt`?

Comment: no empty lines.

Comment: Update `usernab = print(line.strip())` this to `usernab = line.strip()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the print function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258/why-does-the-print-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look at this answer on reading a file line by line.
[How to read a large file, line by line, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

The correct, fully Pythonic way to read a file is the following:

```py
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        # Do something with 'line'
```

From my understanding, what you are trying to do is to check if the username entered by the user is in the list and than `#Do something`.

The first problem is that usernab does not get any value from `usernab = print(line.strip())`, as `print()` does not return anything. Instead you should assign `usernab` the line and than print it:

```py
usernab = line.strip()
print(usernab)
```

The second problem is that you are trying to use `x` witch is a string to iterate in a range of ints. You are basically saying: "For each string in the range 0 to 5, #Do something". You should use another variable.

Furthermore, `if (x) in (usernab)` will check if usernab CONTAINS x. Depending on what you want to do, you might want to change this.

This code compiles under Python 3.7. It will add `1` to `i` five times, each time `x` is found in a line.

```py
f = open("users.txt", "r")

x = str(input("Please enter a valid username: "))

i=0

for line in f:

     usernab = line.strip()
     print(usernab)

     if (x) in (usernab):
            for j in range(0,5):
                i+=1

print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points apart from just the answer:

a) Python's input() by default returns a string, you don't need to convert by using a string conversion.
b)There's a better way to read a file in python using the keyword- 'with'.
c) You are iterating a loop after checking condition with same variable - 'x'. Seems wrong!
d) TO answer the question:
the function strip returns None, and you are trying to iterate over it,so the error. Instead you can directly replace your code as:

```
answer = "2"
if answer == "2":
    f = open("users.txt", "r")    
    x = input("Please enter a valid username: ")
    for line in f:

         if (x) in (line.strip()):
                for i in range(0,5):
                    print('Hi',x)
```