# How to fix "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'"?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have to create this program that lets the user input their age and if they have a discount.  I then have to use `if/elif/else` statements to output the age range and discount price etc.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It says

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

```
#1. Input (Age and discount)
print("Welcome to the Toronto Zoo!")
age = int(input("Please input your age: "))
coupon = input("Do you have a coupon? (Y or N): ")

repeat = "Y"
#2. Process (Calculate age group, discount(if applicable), HST)
while repeat == "Y" :
    if age<=17 and coupon == "Y": #If the user is under 18 and has a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Child")
        price = print("Your Ticket price: $18.99")
        hst= round(price*0.13, 2)
        final = round(price-hst, 2)
        discount= round(final*0.10, 2)
        coupon= round(final-discount, 2)
        print("Your discount is: $", discount)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", coupon)
    elif age<=17 and coupon == "N" : #If the user is under 18 and doesn't have a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Child")
        priceN = print("Your Ticket price: $18.99")
        hstN= round(priceN*0.13, 2)
        finalN = round(priceN-hstN, 2)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", finalN)
    elif age==18 or age<=64 and coupon== "Y": #If the user is aged from 18-64 and has a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Adult")
        price2 = print("Your Ticket price: $28.99")
        hst2= round(price2*0.13, 2)
        final2 = round(price2-hst2, 2)
        discount2= round(final2*0.10, 2)
        coupon2= round(final2-discount2, 2)
        print("Your discount is: $", discount2)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", coupon2)
    elif age==18 or age<=64 and coupon== "N": #If the user is aged from 18-64 and doesn't have a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Adult")
        priceN2 = print("Your Ticket price: $28.99")
        hstN2= round(priceN2*0.13, 2)
        finalN2 = round(priceN2-hstN2, 2)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", finalN2)
    elif age>64 and coupon== "Y": #If the user is above 64 years old and has a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Senior")
        price3 = print("Your Ticket price: $23.99")
        hst3= round(price3*0.13, 2)
        final3 = round(price3-hst3, 2)
        discount3= round(final3*0.10, 2)
        coupon3= round(final3-discount3, 2)
        print("Your discount is: $", discount3)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", coupon3)
    elif age>64 and coupon== "N": #If the user is above 64 years old and doesn't have a coupon, this code block will run
        print("Your Age Category: Senior")
        price = print("Your Ticket price: $23.99")
        priceN3 = print("Your Ticket price: $28.99")
        hstN3= round(priceN3*0.13, 2)
        finalN3 = round(priceN2-hstN3, 2)
        print("Your final cost, including HST sales tax, will be: $", finalN3)
    else:
        print("This is invalid.")

repeat= input("Would you like to repeat this program again? Enter Y or N: ")
print("Thank you for using the Ticket Cost Program.")
```

Comment: See: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) TL;DR you have to provide your attempted code before we can help you, because this is a site to get help with existing code, not to have people write code for you from scratch.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this because you have now provided your code.

Comment: Also your issue is clearly `price = print("Your Ticket price: $18.99")`. `print` doesn't return anything, so `price` will be `None`, meaning `price*0.13` is going to fail. Maybe you meant `price = 18.99`? You have this problem in multiple places in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the print function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258/why-does-the-print-function-return-none)

Comment: 1) Next time you post the error, post the *full* error message, which indicates the exact lines that triggered the error. That would be faster than people reading through your entire code. 2) Learn to debug errors like this yourself, by going to the lines indicated by the error message, and `print`ing out values for `price`, `hst`, `final` and other variables to find out which was `None`.

Comment: print is ok is sometimes. for a better quality of life learn the basics about how to use a debugger, [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) (py 3) or [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) (py2). There are a lot of tutorial out there (the official docs is even better). Basically, just with `s`, `n`, `c`, `l` you can do great things... https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Answer (score 0):

You have several lines like this, where you're expecting `print()` to return something:

```
price = print("Your Ticket price: $18.99")
hst= round(price*0.13, 2)
```

This, however, won't work, because `print()` doesn't return anything, so `price` will be `None`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258/why-does-the-print-function-return-none) for info on why `print()` doesn't return anything.

It's not clear what you expect to be returned from `print`; it seems that you want `price` to be a number, like `18.99`, since you're multiplying it by something. In that case, you'd have to assign it a value, and put the print in its own line:

```
print("Your Ticket price: $18.99")
price = 18.99
hst= round(price*0.13, 2)
```

If you wanted to print out the price, you could use an [f string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to include the price value in the printed text:

```
price = 18.99
print(f"Your Ticket price: ${round(price, 2)}")
hst= round(price*0.13, 2)
```

Regardless of the option you choose, you'd have to also do this for `priceN`, `price2`, and all other instances of this same issue.