# Why is the type of a function <class 'NoneType'>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nonetype

After running the following code. I observed that the return type of a `print()` is None. Please explain why and how is it so?

```
>>> v = print(7)                                                                                                                     >>> v                                                                                                                   >>> type(v)                                                                                                             <class 'NoneType'>                                                                                                      >>>  
>>> type(print(y))
7
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: `type(print)` returns type of function, `type(print())` returns type of value returned from function

Comment: You didn't declare `v` as a function, you declared it to be the *return value* of a particular function call (which returned `None`).  If you did `v = print` or maybe `v = lambda: print(y)` then `v` would be a function and your `type` call would show `<class 'function'>`.

Comment: The part where you typed `>>> v` and got the output `7` would not really happen. It would give no output.

Comment: Now I've corrected the typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

`type(print)`

if you add the parenthesis it calls the function and `type()` will give you the type of the return value

Answer (score 0):

If a function does not return anything, it returns None in python.

You are confusing print with return. The job of print function is to just convert value to string and print, it doesn't return anything, so it is 'NoneType'.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27959293/8512384) for further detailed explanation.