# why output of 'for in one line' is printed in above lines?

Tags: python, for-loop

my code is....

```
names = ['ali', 'parham', 'hasan', 'farhad']
print('names: ', [print(i) for i in names])
```

and my output is this...

```
ali
parham
hasan
farhad
names:  [None, None, None, None]
```

but i want this....

```
names: ali, parham, hasan, farhad
```

why what are in the list is 'None'?!

and why the name are in the above lines?!

Comment: Because `print` returns `None`.

Comment: Change your second line to `print('names: ', [i for i in names])`

Comment: @Ilia isn't `[i for i in names]` just a weird way to write `names`? Why should they change their second line to include such a pointless thing?

Comment: @Ilia `[i for i in names]` is the same as `names`, no? Just use `print('names:', names)`

Comment: "and why the name are in the above lines?!" to evaluate `[print(i) for i in names]`, python needs to first evaluate the function calls `print(i)` and those function calls of course print what they are asked to print.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the print function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258/why-does-the-print-function-return-none)

Comment: @JohnColeman , @jarmod yes, of course, you are both correct. The list comprehension is useless in this case. `print('names': names)` is sufficient.

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a function. Every function returns some value once it finishes, and if it doesn't, it return `None` by default. You can just use `print("names: ", names)` to get the output you want.

Comment: It isn't clear just what output you want, `print('names:', ', '.join(names))` is my guess.

Comment: @lia its print ```names:  ['ali', 'parham', 'hasan', 'farhad']```
i want something like ```names:  ali, parham, hasan, farhad```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `print('names: ', [print(i) for i in names])` the following happens: To do the first `print` Python has to evaluate the arguments of the function. The second argument is `[print(i) for i in names]`. Here you loop over the names, print them and put the result of the call to `print` in the list. This result is always `None`.

So after this first step all the names are printed and then you're virtually left with `print('names: ', [None, None, None, None])`. Now `print` will output exactly that.

If you want to combine the entries of a list to a string use the strings `join` method. Here are some examples from the interactive interpreter.

```
>>> '-'.join(['A', 'B', 'C'])
'A-B-C'
>>> 'x'.join(['A', 'B', 'C'])
'AxBxC'
>>> ' '.join(['A', 'B', 'C'])
'A B C'
>>> values = ['x', 'yy', 'zzz']
>>> ' + '.join(values)
'x + yy + zzz'
>>> names = ['ali', 'parham', 'hasan', 'farhad']
>>> ', '.join(names)
'ali, parham, hasan, farhad'
```

So what you need here is:

```
print('names:', ', '.join(names))
```

or with an f-string

```
print(f"names: {', '.join(names)}")
```

This will give you `names: ali, parham, hasan, farhad`.