# No outcome in the dataframe

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[image]

In line 66, I wonder why the outcome is blank when I make a data frame.

Comment: Remove the `print` statement. It returns `None` and hence subtitle is `None`

Comment: PS : Avoid posting screenshots in questions. Read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thank you so much! I solve the problem :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the print function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258/why-does-the-print-function-return-none)