# How to use print function with for in an interactive session

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Simple question about print function (python 3.9.13) what causes these (a link to some informative page will be appreciated). I have a list of strings and I want to print them each on separate line in an interactive session.

```
>>> aa = ['word 1','test 2', 'blah 3', 'ding 4']
>>> [print(x) for x in aa]
word 1
test 2
blah 3
ding 4
[None, None, None, None]
>>> (print(x) for x in aa)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001D8AC975DD0>
>>> print(x) for x in aa
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> {print(x) for x in aa}
word 1
test 2
blah 3
ding 4
{None}
>>>
```

Question: could you explain these behaviours, especially what causes those None to appear and how to avoid it?

[Edit:] Related posts: ["Why does the print function return None"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27959258/11199684) (but no loops or list actions there), and ["Is it pythonic to use list comprehensions just for side effect?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753719/11199684) (but more abstract, no print function there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[print(x) for x in aa]`, `{print(x) for x in aa}` are list and dictionary comprehensions. `(print(x) for x in aa)` is a generator comprehension. The syntax can be read as:

For each element `x` in the iterable `aa`, emplace the return value of `(print(x)` into a list/set. So for each element `x`, `print(x)` is executed, prints the result and returns `None`. You are seeing that `print` resulted in each element being printed, but also see the resulting list, that only contains `None`.

See https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions for list comprehensions

What you can do is to write

```
for x in aa: print(x)
```

on a single line and then hit enter twice

Answer (score 2):

`None` appears in these areas because `print` returns `None` (I could try to explain this, but others on StackOverflow have explained this better, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return/7664904#7664904).

#### `>>> [print(x) for x in aa]`

Because the output of `print("foo")` is None, the output of `[print(x) for x in aa]` is going to be `[None, None, None None]`, (one `None` for each element of `aa`.

#### `>>> (print(x) for x in aa)`

This creates a [generator object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), something which can later be iterated over:

```
o = (print(x) for x in aa)

for i in o:
    i

# output is 
1
2
3
4
5
```

#### `>>> {print(x) for x in aa}`

This is similar to example #1, except instead of creating a list, it creates a set (basically an unordered list with only unique values). Since there is only one unique value in the list `[None, None, None None]`, the whole thing is reduced down to `{None}`

#### How to avoid it

The simplest way of avoiding it is to use `print` outside of things similar to list comprehensions. Instead of `[print(x) for x in aa]`, do `print([x for x in aa])`. Also, if you create functions, have them return values, then call the function with print, instead of having the function end by printing a value.

Comment: here's another thing to read on this: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-none-printed

Comment: `print([x for x in aa])` gives the same output as `print(aa)`

Comment: ah apologies! I was just using them as standins. I'll make that clearer